How to align text to the bottom right of centered image
I have a figure at the centre of the page.
I would like to keep it centered, but write text to its right, to the bottom.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ ccc }
        & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{../icons/fig.png} & text to the bottom right
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}

The result I want to get is:

But instead I get: (the red line is the centre of the page:


Is the text supposed to be a caption?

Not a caption, as in the image above..

Too bad. If it were supposed to be a caption, you could have used the hvfloat package which has tons of option to place captions besides images.

Your example is not working, because of the usage of a not available image. So I've replaced it by a free available example from mwe.
If I understand correctly, what you want, you can indeed use a table, but a tabularx instead of a tabular:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xc>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
  \hfill & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image} & text to the bottom right
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}

I've also added package showframe to visualize the text area.

But if you already know the width of the image as in your example given by the width option to \includegraphics you can even use this information:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspace*{\dimeval{(\textwidth-0.25\textwidth)/2}}% 0.25\textwidth is the width of the image
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
\hfill
text to the bottom right
\end{document}

Same result as above.
You can also place several lines of text bottom aligned:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}Xc>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X@{}}
  \hfill & \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image} & text to\par the
  bottom right
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}

or
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspace*{\dimeval{(\textwidth-0.25\textwidth)/2}}% 0.25\textwidth is the width of the image
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
\parbox[b]{\dimeval{(\textwidth-0.25\textwidth)/2}}{%
  \raggedleft
  text to the\\
  bottom right
}  
\end{document}

Both with the result:

or
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\hspace*{\dimeval{(\textwidth-0.25\textwidth)/2}}% 0.25\textwidth is the width of the image
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
  text to the\\
  bottom right
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}

with different alignment of the text:


Thank you! This is exactly what I want. Would it be possible to add another line of text above this one?

Excellent! Thanks very much!

For a fixed distance, you can do like this
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% just for the example
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\imagerights}[1]{%
  \unskip
  \makebox[0pt][l]{\scriptsize\quad\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\imagerights{This image is \\ not copyrighted}

\caption{A centered picture with a note on its side}

\end{figure}

\end{document}

Just remember not to leave a blank line before \imagerights.

If you want the text flush with the right margin:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% just for the example
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\imagerights}[1]{%
  \unskip\hfil
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
  \hfilneg
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\includegraphics[width=0.3\columnwidth]{example-image-9x16}
\imagerights{This image is \\ not copyrighted}

\caption{A centered picture with a note on its side}

\end{figure}

\end{document}



Just use \rlap{...}.  No tabular needed.  Horizontal gap is adjustable (currently one space wide).  Note baseline at bottom of image.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{example-image}%
    \rlap{ text to the bottom right}

\end{document}

